# Node/NPM: How to pass arguments with .sh file call

Tags: node.js, npm, development-environment, npm-install, production-environment

I am using `package.json`'s script block to call `postinstall.sh` script immediately after `yarn install` and `yarn install --production`.

`postinstall.sh` contains some private  `npm`  packages, so we want to download `devDependencies` of those packages only when the **environment** is development and we want to ignore when the environment is **production**.

**package.json**

```
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh"
  }
```

**postinstall.sh**

```
 # Get the input from user to check server is Production or not
echo
echo "INFO: We are not downloading Development dependencies of following services in Production environment:
echo "WARN: please enter 'yes' or 'no' only."

while [[ "$PRODUCTION_ENV" != "yes" && "$PRODUCTION_ENV" != "no" ]]
do
  read -p "Is this Production environment?(yes/no): " PRODUCTION_ENV
done

if [[ "$PRODUCTION_ENV" == "yes" ]]; then
   ENV='--only=production'
fi

npm install $ENV --ignore-scripts pkg-name
```

**The problem with above script is we don't want any user interaction**, so how can I pass an argument from `package.json` depending on the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, simple answer to this is `"postinstall": "./postinstall.sh \"$NODE_ENV\""`. So, final look a like below.

```
"private": true,
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh \"$NODE_ENV\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in package.json you should be able to check `NODE_ENV` and then only execute your bash script when it's not production:

```
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" != production ] && ./postinstall.sh"
  }
```

This should work because on a production environment you would install your modules with `npm install --production` so the script will not run.

Comment: That way I tried. In our case, that doesn't work because we want to run postinstall.sh on both environment.